# Errors while looping through the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object let's say items and I am trying to loop through this objects and I am having this errors " cannot convert undefined or null to the object.

```js
let items = {
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  currency: "usd"
}
const result = Object.keys(items).map(index => index.name);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I think you want `items[index]` rather than `index.name`

Comment: or just `const result = Object.values(items)`

Comment: Maybe no need for map, just `Object.keys(items)`

Comment: expected output should be name1/usd this is how I have to use in my code

Comment: If you want to loop through the object you use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). `for(let key in items) { // do something with key or items[key] }`

Comment: i tried to display the name only but undefined...

Comment: If you just want to get name then use `items.name` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the keys, use `Object.keys`. The values, `Object.values`:

```js
let items = {
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  currency: "usd"
};
const keys = Object.keys(items);
const vals = Object.values(items);
console.log(keys);
console.log(vals);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Based on your current code with `Object.keys`, I think you want `items[index]` not `index.name`:

```js
let items = {
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  currency: "usd"
}
const result = Object.keys(items).map(index => items[index]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what If i want to display "name1" out of this object

Answer (score 0):

When you map over the keys, you get the keys and not the object. Also `Object.keys` itself returns an array of keys, if however you want values, use `Object.values()`

```js
    let items = {
      id: 1,
      name: "name1",
      currency: "usd"
    }
    const result = Object.keys(items);
    const sol = Object.values(items);
    console.log(result, sol);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the really code, maybe it can help you.
Object.keys(object) will returns an array of object's keys

```
Object.keys(items) // => ['id', 'name', 'currency']

['id', 'name', 'currency'].map(index =>n. index)//there is no ‘name’ attribute, so it will definitely be undefined
```

Comment: This will result in errors and `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Use `items[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to map. Just use

```
Object.values(items) for values
```

or

```
Object.keys(items) for keys
```

```js
let items = {
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  currency: "usd"
}
const result = Object.values(items)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```
const items = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'name1',
  currency: 'usd'
};
```

`console.log(Object.keys(items)); //outputs ['id','name','currency']`

Since you have used, `Object.keys(items).map(index => index.name);`

`id.name` will be `undefined` hence you are getting `undefined`

So, You can use

```
const result = Object.keys(items).map(index => items[index]);
```

which will result in [1, 'name1', 'usd']

Comment: Please take a look about [Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and use proper Markdown tags

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `keys` and `values` of the given `object` like this

```js
let items = {
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  currency: "usd"
}
Object.keys(items).forEach(function(key, index) {
   console.log("key=>", key, ", index=>", index,", value=>", items[key]);
})
```